# What is the build number of the iOS 8.0 public release?

Tags: ios, ios8

What is the build number of today's iOS 8.0 public release? For reference, *iOS 8.0 GM* is *12A365*.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the question but I was just wondering for what reason you wanted to know? +1

Comment: To know whether I needed to update my GM build or not. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12A365. Exactly the same as the GM.

Comment: Good to know, no need to update from GM then. I wonder if the GM will be capable of OTA updates to 8.0.1, etc.

Comment: Since the GM for 7 was OTA updatable, I would expect so. Moreover, the GM is exactly the same software that has been shipped on the iPhone 6 so, again, it has to be OTA updatable.